# How to export instance from Google Compute Engine to other clouds

Tags: amazon-ec2, vmware, google-compute-engine

How Can I migrate instance from Google Compute Engine to other cloud like Amazon, Vsphere using java client API.

Answer (score 0):

[If you are running your stack in a Docker container](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/container_vms), then you could move your docker image to the new provider if this provider also supports Docker.

Comment: Thanks @koma. I am writing a wrapper on GCE, I want to create a raw image from running  instance and then migrate it to another cloud provider. I completed this using commands (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images), now i want to create this using Java client API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [terraform.io](https://www.terraform.io/) to describe your infrastructure as code. It isn't possible to use the exact same syntax for different cloud providers, but it definitely is easy to migrate.

If I had to "migrate" instances, I would do that. About migrating the data (i.e. bucket), that's a different problem, and should be solved by mirroring, synchronizing, and shutting down the unused one after instance migration.